# I'm struggling to manipulate the necessary equations to find the final temperature and pressure

Tags: chemical-engineering

A perfectly insulated tank is divided into two identical chambers separated by an internal
membrane. One chamber contains methane at 500 bar and 20 °C. The other chamber is evacuated
(contains nothing). There is no heat transfer between the tank walls and the gas. The membrane
suddenly bursts. Calculate the temperature and pressure of the gas in the tank in its final equilibrium
state, assuming CH4 follows

b. the van der Waals equation of state
c. the Peng-Robinson equation of state

Comment: What happens when a gas suddenly expands?

Comment: I think you will continue to struggle, I don't know how to determine 2 variables like this,

Comment: Can you write the state equation for the situation in the methane chamber at the start and then the similar situation for methane after it expanded into the whole vessel?

Comment: Show us what you know.  We are not a homework service.